# how to graph data from log file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a log file that has a trades summary, the log file looks like this

```
date        time       amt     sell/buy     type    current_price 
2020-08-03 01:20:06    1.5    0.00187130    SELL    0.00187030
2020-08-03 01:23:20    1.1    0.00187110    SELL    0.00187090
2020-08-03 01:26:36    1.8    0.00187190    SELL    0.00187070
2020-08-03 01:29:52    1.3    0.00187160    SELL    0.00186820
2020-08-03 01:36:24    1.4    0.00186580    BUY    0.00186780
2020-08-03 01:39:41    1.4    0.00186860    SELL    0.00186640
2020-08-03 01:42:54    1.3    0.00186710    BUY    0.00186880
2020-08-03 01:46:10    1.0    0.00186990    SELL    0.00186980
2020-08-03 01:49:25    1.2    0.00186840    BUY    0.00186850
```

my goal is to graph the data inside this log file the values I want to graph are the `date_time` format the `sell/buy` price and the `current_price` i read the lines from the log file with `readlines` and for each line, I append `date_time` and `current_price` to `date_time_lst` and `current_prices_lst` then for each trade I append the `sell/buy` price and `date_time` to other lists, this is obviously not efficient and time-consuming also when I get the graph with `plt.show` I get the values that are out of order on the graph.

as you can see the y-axis is not in ascending or descending order, what I am doing wrong and how can I improve on this

[image]

```
date_time_lst = []
current_price_lst = [] 
BUYS_prices_lst = [] 
SELLS_prices_lst = [] 
BUYS_DATES =[]
SELLS_DATES = [] 





with open(file__name , "r") as r_handle:
    log_lines = r_handle.readlines()
for line in log_lines:
    line = line.split()
    
    date_time_lst.append(str(line[0] + " " + line[1]))
    current_price_lst.append(line[5])



    if line[4] == "SELL":
            ## the amount of BNB multiplyed by the sell price returns the amount of bitcoin we get from the trade
        amt = float(line[2])*float(line[3])
        SELLS_prices_lst.append(line[3])
        SELLS_DATES.append(str(line[0] + " " + line[1]))
        ## the amount above gets added to the qoute_balance (bitcoin_balance)
        qoute_balance += amt


        ## the original BNB amount is subtracted from the base_balance (binance_balance)
        base_balance -= float(line[2])

    

    elif line[4] == "BUY":
        amt_ = float(line[2])*float(line[3])
        qoute_balance += amt_
        base_balance -= float(line[2])
        BUYS_prices_lst.append(line[3])
        BUYS_DATES.append(str(line[0] + " " + line[1]))



plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'grey'
plt.grid(color="black")
plt.scatter(date_time_lst , current_price_lst, color='green' , label='current_coin_prices')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the values that are out of order on the graph.

- The numbers are read as strings. Turn them into floats before appending them to the lists.

  - ```
    price = float(line[3])
    current = float(line[5])
    ```
- Turn the date and time columns into a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

  - ```
    dt = line[0] + ' ' + line[1]
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ```

Comment: thanks for the help but  ```dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')```